# Make result display SQL commands with table data: 'select with 'insert into table_name select value1 value2' '

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, insert

I want to query a table but I want it to also output the SQL commands for each row.

For example: DISPLAY SQL COMMANDS as a result but with the **data** filled with that rows values.

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT DATA1, DATA2. DATA3 From Table2 WHERE Table2.ID=1
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your data and desired output.  I can't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table1 
output inserted.data1, inserted.data2, inserted.data3
SELECT DATA1, DATA2. DATA3 From Table2 WHERE Table2.ID=1
```